# Array of struct initialization using variadic macro

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, variadic-macros

I have the following type definition:

```
typedef struct {
  int (*function)(int argc, char *argv[]);
  char *name;
} command_t;
```

The member `function` is a function pointer and the member `name` is a string which will store the name of the function.

To initialize a variable of type `command_t`, I wrote the following macro:

```
#define COMMAND(x) (command_t){.function = x, .name = #x}
```

Here's how I currently initialize an array of `command_t`:

```
int ls(int argc, char *argv[]);
int echo(int argc, char *argv[]);
int cat(int argc, char *argv[]);
int mkdir(int argc, char *argv[]);

command_t cmd_list[] = {COMMAND(ls), COMMAND(echo), COMMAND(cat), COMMAND(mkdir)};
```

I would like to be able to initialize an array of `command_t` as such:

```
command_t cmd_list[] = COMMAND(ls, echo, cat, mkdir);
```

or

```
command_t cmd_list[] = {COMMAND(ls, echo, cat, mkdir)};
```

I know that `COMMAND` has to be a variadic macro to do so but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: I don't think it can be done with variadic macros. The preprocessor does not have the capability to deconstruct the VA_ARGS and process each arg. It can only do a simple expand of the VA_ARGS in its body. IMHO X-macros would be more appropriate here.

Comment: "I would like to be able to initialize an array of command_t as such"  Why? It doesn't improve readability much, it just makes your code look more mysterious. If anything you should make a macro for the whole init list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are already close to the most readable form. Try to create the code as simple as possible. So instead of inventing some strange macro that no C programmer understands what it does without going though a jungle of macros, you could make a macro for the whole initializer list - that's fairly common practice.

That is: `command_t cmd_lst[] = COMMAND_INIT;` And then:

```
#define COMMAND(cmd) { .function = cmd, .name = #cmd }
#define COMMAND_INIT { COMMAND(ls), COMMAND(echo), COMMAND(cat), COMMAND(mkdir) }
```

---

Yet another option is X macros. They are not necessarily more readable, but could maybe lead to reduction of code repetition elsewhere:

```
#define FUNC_LIST(X) \
  X(ls)              \
  X(echo)            \
  X(cat)             \
  X(mkdir)           \

...

#define COMMAND_INIT(func) { .function = func, .name = #func },  
command_t cmd_lst[] = { FUNC_LIST(COMMAND_INIT) };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//stringification of the argument Arg
#define PP_STRINGIFY(Arg) PP_STRINGIFY_(Arg)
#define PP_STRINGIFY_(Arg) #Arg

//concatenation of the two arguments
#define PP_CAT2(_1, _2) PP_CAT_(_1, _2)
#define PP_CAT_(_1, _2) _1##_2

//enumerate the number of arguments (min:1, max: 8)
#define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS(...) PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
#define PP_VA_NUM_ARGS_(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,N,...) N

//a single command initializer
#define COMMAND(x) (command_t){.function = x, .name = PP_STRINGIFY(x)}

//command list initializer
#define COMMAND_LST(...) { PP_CAT2(COMMAND_LST_,PP_VA_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__) }

//implement as many as you need
//maybe you need to extend PP_VA_NUM_ARGS (current max limit 8)
#define COMMAND_LST_1(_1) COMMAND(_1)
#define COMMAND_LST_2(_1,_2) COMMAND(_1), COMMAND(_2)
#define COMMAND_LST_3(_1,_2,_3) COMMAND_LST_2(_1,_2), COMMAND(_3)
#define COMMAND_LST_4(_1,_2,_3,_4) COMMAND_LST_3(_1,_2,_3), COMMAND(_4)

typedef struct {
    int (*function)(int argc, char *argv[]);
    char *name;
} command_t;

int ls(int argc, char *argv[]);
int echo(int argc, char *argv[]);
int cat(int argc, char *argv[]);
int mkdir(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main()
{
    command_t cmd_lst[] = COMMAND_LST(ls, echo, cat, mkdir);
    return 0;
}
```

CPP output via

```
gcc -E main.c
```

gives you

```
command_t cmd_lst[] = { 
    (command_t){.function = ls, .name = "ls"}, 
    (command_t){.function = echo, .name = "echo"}, 
    (command_t){.function = cat, .name = "cat"}, 
    (command_t){.function = mkdir, .name = "mkdir"} 
};
```